# Elements in dual of isomorphic space

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $c_0$ is equipped with an equivalent norm and we consider $c_0^*$ the dual of $c_0$ with this new norm. I know that $x\in\ell^1$ acts on $c_0$ by $x(z)=\sum_nx_nz_n$ for any $z\in c_0$. I'd like to know if the same is true for $c_0*$. If $x\in c_0^*$, is it true that $x(z)=\sum_nx_nz_n$?

Comment: Yes, $c_0^{\ast}$ is isomorphic to $\ell^1$, if that is what you are asking. The proof is simple to begin with: Take $x\in c_0^{\ast}$ and evaluate it on the standard basis vector $e_n$. This gives you a candidate sequence $(z_n)$. You have to then show that $(z_n) \in \ell^1$, which is worth trying.

Comment: I think what I'm asking is the following: If $X$ is the dual of $c_0$ with the usual norm, there is a one to one correspondence between $X$ and $\ell^1$ by $f(x)=\varphi_x$, where $\varphi_x(z)=\sum_nx_nz_n$ for every $x\in\ell^1$. Now if $c_0^*$ is the dual of $c_0$ with some equivalent norm, if we look at the one to one correspondence $f'(x)=\varphi_x\in c_0^*$, the question is, do we consider $f'$ mapping from $\ell^1$, as we did with $f$. And also, does $f'(x)$ act the same way on an element of $c_0$ as $f(x)$ does (when you say take $x\in c_0^*$ and act on $e_n$, we need to know how).